# Modify formula stored in string via VBA

Tags: regex, vba, excel

(I have hundreds of rows need to change. The data is like this

```
activity_id equation
5225518         D0312_ABC * (S3765+S3790+S3762+S3763+S3770+S3764+S4480) * (1-(S2820+S0560))*(1-S1965)*(1-C0151)
7306234         D0300_BCD * C0502 * (1-(S0191))*(1-S1965)
8293425         D0798_CDE * P0692 * (1-(S0191+S2820+S0560+S0290+S0960))*(1-S1965)
9119429         D0793_DEF * S2605 * (1-S0290)*(1-S1965)
```

I need to combine the two "1-something" together and there is a pattern. 
When ever there is a `(1-(Sxxx+Sxxxx))*(1-(Sxxx+Sxxxx))`, 
combine them into one which is `(1-(Sxxx+Sxxxx +Sxxx+Sxxxx))`

So I only need to change everything with Sxxxx, you can ignore Cxxxx, Dxxxx, Pxxxx, ...

SO I need to change it to:

```
activity_id equation
5225518          D0312_ABC * (S3765+S3790+S3762+S3763+S3770+S3764+S4480) * (1-(S2820+S0560+S1965))*(1-C0151)
7306234          D0300_BCD * C0502 * (1-(S0191+S1965))
8293425          D0798_CDE * P0692 * (1-(S0191+S2820+S0560+S0290+S0960+S1965))
9119429          D0793_DEF * S2605 * (1-(S0290+S1965))
```

Comment: It's either pretty easy (if you always have `(1-(a+b+c...))*(1-z)` in the formula) or very difficult (if it's actually a freeform formula).

Comment: Impossible given that there is no pattern.

Comment: @findwindow Not impossible, just very difficult. Or [very easy](https://www.google.com/search?q=simplify+mathematical+expressions+online), depending on what is an acceptable solution.

Comment: @GSerg I don't see a pattern between first and third. But I am very bad at math.

Comment: Ah, you should put that in the OP. I only focused on `-` not letters.

Comment: Still painful given that sometimes there's a `(` and sometimes not XD And it's not like you showed any effort so...

Comment: @pnuts Also need to replace the `-`s with `+`s.

Comment: Well it would now appear this is also true 'for real' @pnuts!

Comment: @GSerg : Your answered disappeared before I can press the *Add Comment*!^^ Even thought it is not working for every line, could you post it as a proposition in an edit or somewhere else? :)

Comment: @R3uK I realised my answer was not correct given the clarified requirements, then I realised it might be correct anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The following regexp certainly may and arguably should be improved.

```
Option Explicit

Private m_Rex As RegExp

Private Const SEARCH_PATTERN As String = "\(1-\(?((S\d{4}\+?)+)\)?\)\*\(1-\(?((S\d{4}\+?)+)\)?\)"
'                                                $0                          $2
Private Const REPLACE_PATTERN As String = "(1-($1+$3))"


Public Function Simplify(ByVal AVeryParticularFormula As String) As String
  If m_Rex Is Nothing Then
    Set m_Rex = New RegExp
    m_Rex.Global = False
    m_Rex.MultiLine = False
    m_Rex.IgnoreCase = False
    m_Rex.Pattern = SEARCH_PATTERN
  End If

  Do
    Simplify = m_Rex.Replace(AVeryParticularFormula, REPLACE_PATTERN)
    If Simplify = AVeryParticularFormula Then Exit Do

    AVeryParticularFormula = Simplify
  Loop

End Function
```

```
? Simplify("D0312_ABC * (S3765+S3790+S3762+S3763+S3770+S3764+S4480) * (1-(S2820+S0560))*(1-S1965)*(1-C0151)")
D0312_ABC * (S3765+S3790+S3762+S3763+S3770+S3764+S4480) * (1-(S2820+S0560+S1965))*(1-C0151)

? Simplify("D0300_BCD * C0502 * (1-(S0191))*(1-S1965)")
D0300_BCD * C0502 * (1-(S0191+S1965))

? Simplify("D0798_CDE * P0692 * (1-(S0191+S2820+S0560+S0290+S0960))*(1-S1965)")
D0798_CDE * P0692 * (1-(S0191+S2820+S0560+S0290+S0960+S1965))

? Simplify("D0793_DEF * S2605 * (1-S0290)*(1-S1965)")
D0793_DEF * S2605 * (1-(S0290+S1965))
```

Comment: Nicely done anyways! Under 45min while keeping an eye on the comments! I've not worked enough with regex to do this myself and I now will have base to work/play with! So thank you too! ;)

Comment: Didn't know function did not have to return something.

Comment: @findwindow This function returns something, and in the only way VB6(A) supports.